# How to turn variable values to variable names?

Tags: r

I have series of variables and values :

```
var1<- "MyVar1"
var2<- "MyVar2"
...
varN<- "MyVarN"

values1 <- c("a","b", "c")
values2 <- c("d","e", "f", "g")
...
valuesN <- c(...)
```

The number N and the values of varX and valuesX are known at runtime (supplied by the user).

I need to turn them into a function parameter such as:

```
globalvar = list(MyVar1=c("a","b", "c"), MyVar2=c("d","e", "f", "g"), ... varN=c(...))
```

and then supply it to the function myfunction():

```
myfunction(globalvar = list(MyVar1=c("a","b", "c"), MyVar2=c("d","e", "f", "g"), ... varN=c(...)), other_parameters)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a more concise way of doing this:

```
# Helper function to extract values / names
read <- function (prefix) function (i) get(paste0(prefix, i))

# Collect arguments
args <- setNames(lapply(1 : N, read('values')), lapply(1 : N, read('var')))

# Call function
myfunction(globalvar = args, other_parameters)
```

The argument collection still contains a slight repetition since we’re doing essentially the same for the values and their names but I think that’s permissible here, in particular since we’ve generalised their actual work into the `read` helper.

Notice also that your solution of using a separate environment isn’t actually necessary. You’re essentially just copying the variables from `myListe` into a new list `tmp` in a convoluted fashion.

Comment: Nice and concise :-) Thanks Konrad!

Answer (score 1):

```
var3 <- list(values1, values2, ..., valuesN)
names(var3) <- c("MyVar1", "MyVar2", ... "MyVarN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with this solution:

```
    myListe <- list()      
    for (i in 1:N) {
      var.name          <- get(paste("var",i,sep=""))
      var.values        <- get(paste("values",i,sep="")) 

      myListe[i]        <- list(var.values)
      names(myListe)[i] <- list(var.name)

    }

    tmp     <- new.env()  ; assign('globalvar',as.list(myListe),envir=tmp)
```

And then I call the function myfunction() as follows:

```
   do.call(myfunction, c(as.list(tmp),as.list(other_parameters)))
```

Is there a more concise way to do the same thing?

Comment: A more concise way of doing this would be to use vectors/lists instead of numbered variables. In fact, the mere existence of these numbered variables is a problem. Don’t do that.

Comment: I agree. However, the variables are generated by another program. By concise, I mean using lapply or something similar to avoid the for loop. Thanks.